# PageView Container won't constrain to a max width or height flutter

Tags: flutter, debugging

I can't seem to figure out why my container keeps being full screen. I'm trying to make the containers have a max width so when its viewed on a desktop the containers look like cards kinda like they would if it was viewed on a phone screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

int currentPage = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => PageView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            controller: ctrl,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an image of what the container is doing.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8yjL.png)

And here is what I want it to look like when viewed on a desktop

[What I'm Trying To Do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY4gL.png)

I Also tried adding constants like this and that didn't work either.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

int currentPage = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => PageView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            controller: ctrl,
            children: [
              Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /4,
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Could someone help me do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put PageView Inside a container and give constraints to that container.